Make a SpatialAudio source autoplay in Reality Composer Pro?
Is there a way to make a SpatialAudio object autoplay its assigned track strictly via settings in Reality Composer Pro, no Swift code involved?

Playing spatial audio with zero-code in RCP 2.0 scene
Yep, this is possible thanks to the new version of RCP. I chose AtmospheresOcean .caf audio from Reality Composer Pro's free library. Then I put a track in Timelines editor. After that I added the OnAddedToScene behavior with Timeline action on Entity. And do not forget  to supply AudioLibrary resources with AtmospheresOcean sound.

This code is enough to auto-play your spatial sound as soon as the scene starts.
RealityView { rvc in
    let scene = try! await Entity(named: "Immersive", in: rkcb)
    rvc.add(scene)
}


If you do not hear any sound when the scene starts, then reboot your visionOS Simulator using the Device – Erase All Content and Settings... command.

Thanks, this helped! (Most notably by demonstrating that Xcode-beta was launching 1.0 of Reality Composer Pro, not 2.0, which is missing half of these features.)
